# Can we say that a function is increasing/decreasing on some range if there's a vertical asymptote in that range?

Tags: calculus, functions

The graph below shows the function $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x-1}$
Can we say that the function is decreasing for all $x\le2$ (there's a local minimum at $x=2$) or do we have to take the asymptote at $x=1$ into account?

[image: <span class=]$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x-1}$" />

Comment: Well, actually that function isn't decreasing on $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,2]$, because $f(0)<f(2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to take the asymptote into account. The function is decreasing for all $x<1$ and $1<x<2$. A function is decreasing on $x=a$ if $f'(a)<0$. The derivative is undefined of $x=1$, so we can't compare it to 0.

If there is a asymptote or in general a discontinuity, then we can't even say that the function is decreasing on the union of both intervals, as other users pointed out, the function is not decreasing on $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,2)$, however, it is decreasing on $(-\infty,1)$ and on $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm not sure about one thing - shouldn't it be $1\lt x \le2$? I've read that at a local minimum/maximum a function is both increasing and decreasing.

Comment: It depends a bit on your definition of increasing and decreasing. The one uses increasing for $f'(x) > 0$ and non-decreasing for $f'(x) \geq 0$, the other uses strictly increasing for $f'(x) > 0$ and increasing for $f'(x) \geq 0$, and similiar for decreasing. However, its either neither or both.

Comment: I've found an answer to this question from my textbook. It says "The function is decreasing for all defined values of $x \le 2$" So does it imply a union of two intervals (which is wrong according to your second paragraph)?

Comment: It depends a bit on you conventions. A function can be decreasing on all points in a certain set, or on an interval. If the former is meant, the textbook's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

"$f$ is decreasing on $D$" means that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ (or maybe just $\ge$ if you don't require strict decreasing) whenever $x_1,x_2\in D$ with $x_1<x_2$. This is not the case here for $D=(-\infty,1)\cup (1,2)$. However, we could say that $f$ is *locally* decreasing on $D$, that is: Every point $\in D$ has a neighbourhood on which $f$ is decreasing ...